# Getting values from half dynamic JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am working on a project where I have to use data from the dynamic JSON file. This is example of how JSON file could look.

```
{
    "selectors": {
        "title": {
            "css": ".title"
        },
        "url": {
            "css": ".url"
        }
    }
}
```

Because the content of JSON file is dynamic, I can't access object like for example:

```
var data = '{"selectors":{"title":{"css":".title"},"url":{"css":".url"}}}';
var json = JSON.parse(data);   
var element = json.selectors.title.css;
```

However, there are two objects that will always have same name, and those are **selectors** and **css**.

Now how can I access the objects **title**, **url**, **category**, **time** if they are dynamic? AND then to access **css** object trough those?

I need vanila JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: It's best if you do your own work, then ask us when you are stuck. We're not really here to do programming tasks for you. Please read [ask].

Comment: You could use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) to get the dynamic keys in the selector and css "subobjects" . Then, in combination with [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) you can determine if there is a key named 'title' or 'url', etc, and finally get those objects.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't know if a specific attribute exists you need to loop through all of them:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data); 
for (key in json) {

}
```

but to make sure that you only loop through valid objects (and not something someone else might have tampered with) you should check for hasOwnProperty:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data); 
for (key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key) {

  }
}
```

Now you are sure to loop through the first level of attributes, which in your example is only the attribute `selectors`. Now you can add another loop to check the 2nd level of attributes:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data); 
for (key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key) {
    for (second_level in key) {
      if (key.hasOwnProperty(second_level) {
        if (second_level == 'title') { /* do something with title */ }
        if (second_level == 'url') { /* do something with url */ }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

This can get a little messy, but because you expect a specific structure, you can just check for those attributes:

```
if (json.hasOwnProperty('selectors') {
    if (json.selectors.hasOwnProperty('title') { /* do something with title*/ }
    if (json.selectors.hasOwnProperty('url') { /* do something with url */ }
}
```

We can access the attributes title and url directly because in your json these are objects (`{}`) and not arrays (`[]`), if they were arrays you would need to loop through them.

Hope it helps